# Linux Mint Cinnamon ACPI errors by the thousand on boot and shutdown

Tags: linux-mint

On an Asrock H110M-DGS

Anyone got an idea what I can do about this?  I've got nothing back from Asrock as yet.

```
Apr 08 14:49:53 abro kernel: No Arguments are initialized for method [_L6F]
Apr 08 14:49:53 abro kernel: 
Apr 08 14:49:53 abro kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_GPE._L6F due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
Apr 08 14:49:53 abro kernel: ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L6F] (20210730/evgpe-511)
Apr 08 14:49:53 abro kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_GPE._L6F.PGRT], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
Apr 08 14:49:53 abro kernel: 
Apr 08 14:49:53 abro kernel: No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_L6F]
Apr 08 14:49:53 abro kernel: 
Apr 08 14:49:53 abro kernel: No Arguments are initialized for method [_L6F]
Apr 08 14:49:53 abro kernel: 
Apr 08 14:49:53 abro kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_GPE._L6F due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
Apr 08 14:49:53 abro kernel: ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L6F] (20210730/evgpe-511)
Apr 08 14:49:53 abro kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_GPE._L6F.PGRT], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
Apr 08 14:49:53 abro kernel: 
Apr 08 14:4
```

Comment: Which kernel version do you have? You might be bumping into [this reopened bug](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=213023). [This](https://askubuntu.com/a/1376050) appears to be a successful workaround.

Comment: 5.15.0.69 generic.  I tried the workaround and it didn't seem to help

Comment: i tried again and this time i noticed the update-grub was not completing so I checked it and it is in an error loop forever.  I might have aborted it last time without thinking or even knowing (shut down the machine while it was running). Catch-22.  Won't run because of acpi errors:
Apr 15 11:39:07 abro kernel: 
Apr 15 11:39:07 abro kernel: No Arguments are initialized for method [_L6F]
Apr 15 11:39:07 abro kernel: 
Apr 15 11:39:07 abro kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_GPE._L6F due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)